# Unable to include many linux header file such as module.h,interrupt.h etc

Tags: linux

I have tried installing headers even source every time same result.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information...Done
linux-headers-3.16.0-53-generic is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 124 not upgraded.

But in usr/include/linux folder no required header files are present
whereas in in usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-53/include/linux folder required header files are present 
Don't know how to install these header files .

Comment: Please write why you need these header files. There might be a better solution to the *real* problem behind.

Answer (score 2):

Install the `linux-libc-dev` package for header files
in `/usr/include/linux/`.

Answer (score -1):

Don't Use a Simple .cpp File for program ,Create a Project in any IDE. I prefer Code:Blocks, when Created a project of console application in Code:Blocks it solve the problem.I Guess you are practicing on system call.

Comment: You do not need an IDE. You can simply add compiler flags `-I /usr/src/linux-headers-3.16.0-53/include/` by hand or in the CXXFLAGS of the makefile.